# OutlineTextField , TextField not working in Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha02

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For some reason, CoreTextField works but TextField and OutlineTextField wont

### Works

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldDemo(){
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Text")) }
    CoreTextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = text.value,
            onValueChange = {text.value = it})
}
```

### Not working

```
    @Composable
fun TextFieldDemo(){
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Text")) }
    OutlinedTextField(value = text.value,
            onValueChange = {text.value = it}, label = {Text("Test")})
}
```

Error: Non of the following Functions can be called for `OutlinedTextField`

From the docs change

```
Bug Fixes

androidx.ui.foundation.TextFieldValue and androidx.ui.input.EditorValue are deprecated. TextField, FilledTextField and CoreTextField composables that uses that type is also deprecated. Please use androidx.ui.input.TextFieldValue instead (I4066d, b/155211005)
```

But I'm using what it says (I think)

Edit

[image]

Comment: "But I'm using what it says (I think)" -- are you sure that you have the correct `import` for `androidx.ui.input.TextFieldValue`?

Comment: when I import it just lets me import this one import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue

Comment: OK, actually, that should be correct (I was going based off of your quoted documentation, which itself is out of date). And you are using `androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField`?

Comment: With the `1.0.0-alpha02` this code should work.The correct imports are `androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue` and `androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField`

Comment: I have updated the question with the code @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @CoffeeBreak In the code reported in the screen, add the parameter `label = { Text("Test") }`

Comment: I use `implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the "label" param in the original question, as we can see in the image. Following Gabriele's comment made it work, so you shouldn't change the question with the answer, it's a lot confusing.

Just for the record, here it`s the code that works in 1.0.0-alpha02:

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldDemo() {
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Text")) }
    OutlinedTextField(value = text.value,
        onValueChange = { text.value = it },
        label = { Text("Test") })
}
```